# How to restore SMS from sms.vmsg backup?

Tags: sms, 7.0-nougat, restore

I made a backup of my contacts and SMS on an Android 6 phone with what I think is a stock Backup & Restore app. I ended up with two files: `contact.vcf` and `sms.vmsg`.

However, my new phone (Android 7) doesn't have any preloaded Backup & Restore app. I managed to import `contact.vcf` via the address book, however the messaging app doesn't seem to have any option to import backed up SMS.

What can I do with this `sms.vmsg` file to resotre my SMS?

Comment: It might help if you tell us which phone you used to make that backup. Somebody might be able to track that ROM or the APK and make it available to you, as a solution you know. :-)

Comment: @Firelord I assumed this vmsg format was somewhat standard, so there would be a known procedure / app to import such files on Android. In my particular case I still have the old phone (luckily), so I just went ahead and installed SMS Backup & Restore and made a backup in XML. Perhaps I'll delete my question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to open my backup with this [VMG Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aoe.vmgconverter) app. The app requires to buy an unlock code if you want to restore more than 200 messages from the backup, so I didn't use it in the end, but it could have been an option if no other backup was available.

Comment: +1. Thanks for self answering . Might come in handy for someone else :)